# Why does Microsoft Dynamics 365 ask for delegated admin in Azure app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm

I'm following a guide online to generate an access token to access Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement: https://eax360.com/dynamics-365-online-connect-using-postman/.

All of it works fine, however I am wondering why delegated Admin permissions need to be supplied in Azure Active directory during app registration. I have seen a lot of guides explain that permissions must be delegated but the above site documents the process well. As a general rule, I thought that starting with the lowest security permissions was the norm. I am new to Azure AD so thoughts are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your app will be a client which allows the **authenticated user** to perform operations, you must configure the application to have the Access Dynamics 365 as organization users **delegated permission**.

**Application permission** means that you want your app to access Common Data Service without a user.

So whether to use delegated permission in Azure app registration depends on your needs. It is not mandatory.

But we can see that the **Application permissions** in Azure app registration is gray out. This is because Microsoft provides a different way to implement it.

We need to create a Common Data Service application user an then bound it to the registered app. After that, we could connect using the application secret. See the details here: [Connect as an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#connect-as-an-app).